# Using TeX and Glue for title expression in base plots

Tags: r, plot

How can I use `TeX` and `glue` at the same time for a title expression? For example, I want to be able to use mathematical notations, but I also want to include the value of a dynamic variable with `glue`.

An example plot:

```
library(latex2exp)
library(glue)
v = "some dynamic text"
plot(5, 2, main=glue("{TeX('$I^2 +$')}{v}"))
```

The latex expression is not used. Essentially, I need to use greek letters and subscripts and then glue a dynamic text at the end. Is there a way to include both mathematical expression and the glue function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `paste0()` like this:

```
v = "some dynamic text"
plot(5, 2, main=TeX(paste0('$I^2 +$',v)))
```

Comment: Ah this works great! I just have one issue, If I try to use latex as such ```\hat{x}```, I get this error: ```rror: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'$I^2 +\h"```

Comment: it turns out you need two slashes likeso ```\\hat{x}```. Thanks so much! I really needed this